# Next JS Language Switcher redirects Home page, if you are not in Home page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, i18next, react-i18next

I am using `i18n` for changing languages on NextJs. It works, but, if I am in News `'/news'` page for example and if I change language, it redirects to home page `'/'`. I think the reason is changing `middleware.js`, but if change its codes, the app does not work and I get errors `This page isn’t working`, `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. I am using `Next JS 13 beta`

Middleware.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import acceptLanguage from "accept-language";
import { fallbackLng, languages } from "@/app/i18n/settings";

acceptLanguage.languages(languages);

export const config = {
  matcher: "/:lng*",
};

const cookieName = "i18next";

export function middleware(req) {
  let lng;
  if (req.cookies.has(cookieName))
    lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value);
  if (!lng) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.headers.get("Accept-Language"));
  if (!lng) lng = fallbackLng;

  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lng}`, req.url));
  }

  if (req.headers.has("referer")) {
    const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get("referer"));
    const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) =>
      refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`)
    );
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer);
    return response;
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

if I change

```
if (req.nextUrl.pathname !== '/') {
  const newPathname = `/${lng}${req.nextUrl.pathname.replace(/^\/[a-z]{2}\b/, '')}`
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(newPathname, req.url))
}
```

I get errors.

Comment: @JamalFakhriddinov yes, I solved. Change this code

```


  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lng}${req.nextUrl.search}`, req.url));
  }

```